# What's the word for "stationed", but for non-military people?

Tags: word-request

What's the word for "stationed", but for non-military people? I am thinking about non-military personnel such as ambassadors, and other non-military people working abroad.

For example:

> The U.S. ambassadors **are stationed** in Ottawa.
>
> The Canadian government forced the U.S. embassy out of Ottawa and forced them to **set up** in Toronto so the ambassadors would be **stationed** closer to the U.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's the word for "stationed", but for non-military people? I am thinking about non-military personnel such as ambassadors, and other non-military people working abroad.**

You have used the word  "**stationed**" This is technically incorrect although it commonly spoken.  "**stationed at**" would be correct. The word you are looking for is **Posted** and it applies to both **Military and civilians**.

> **post** verb (PLACE) to send someone to a particular place to work: [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/post)
>
> He's been **posted** to Pakistan for six months.
>
> **post** noun (JOB) a job in a company or organisation:
>
> Teaching posts are advertised in Tuesday's edition of the paper.
>
> She's held the post for 13 years.
>
> They have several vacant posts.
>
> **post** noun (PLACE) the particular place where someone works, especially where a soldier is told to be for military duty, usually as a guard:
>
> The soldier was disciplined for deserting his post.
>
> I was ordered to remain at my post until the last customer had left.

Answer (score 1):

Governmental personnel, particularly diplomats, are also said to be "stationed" in a particular country or location.

Private employees are often said to be "assigned" to a particular place, or to be "located" in a place. The first emphasizes the decision of the employer. Other terms might be used, but I think these are the most common ones.